# How do I view the historical versions of HTML,CSS, and ECMAScript

Tags: javascript

How do I view the historical versions of HTML,CSS, and ECMAScript? And how do I know what's updated with each version!

Comment: Read the specifications?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/
https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Thanks captain google :)